# I installed Ubuntu and it hides my other Windows' partitions!

Tags: windows-7, 15.10, windows-8, hidden-files

I just installed **Ubuntu 15.10**. After installing Ubuntu, I am able to access my **Windows 7 OS** again. But it hides all the files. I have tried to view it through Ubuntu and have also tried to enable hidden files. But I have not been able to view my files. How do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: i install ubuntu  15.10 yesterday ,and after installing , am unable to access my windows 7 and 8 opereting system, i tried to remove my HDD so as to view the files on another laptop , but it hides everything, please what can i do

Comment: @emmanuel Add all possible info to the question by editing it but don't repeat the same question in the comments, that's not what they are for.

Comment: Do you mean at the boot screen or the partitions? You have to be a little bit more specific for us to be able to help you.